# php array with csv values, get certain value?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a txt file which has rows like below.

```
apple, green, fruit
banana, yellow, fruit
carrot, orange, vegetable
```

I am trying to get the item, by the color.
So if I have green I want to return apple, if I have yellow I want to return banana.

I do

```
$array = file($file_path);
```

Which outputs

```
Array ( [0] => apple, green, fruit
        [1] => banana, yellow, fruit
        [2] => carrot, orange, vegetable
    )
```

I now want to do something like below, find $input in the position 1 and return position 0 for that row.

```
$input = 'green';
$result = array_search($input, array_column($array, '1', '0')); // return apple.
```

But the $result returns empty. Do I need to convert the CSV to an array, or is there another way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read your csv file; you can start with that and twik as you need
(this is just an example for small files not recommended for large ones)

```php
if (($open = fopen($file_path, "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($open, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $array[] = $data;
    }
 
    fclose($open);
}
 
// Display you array data, so you can make the right search

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each value in $array is a string, like "apple, green, fruit", and not an array like [ apple, green, fruit ]. So you first have to loop over the array and turn each $value into an array to make your code work:

```
$array = [
  'apple, green, fruit',
  'banana, yellow, fruit',
  'carrot, orange, vegetable'
];

$input = 'green';

$arrayWithSubarrays = array_map(fn($value) => explode(', ', $value), $array);

$result = array_search($input, array_column($arrayWithSubarrays, 1, 0));

print_r($result);   // Output: apple
```

Alternative approaches:

If the input array contains a lot of entries you might want to leave the loop early. In that case array_map is an overkill as it will loop over all array entries:

```
$array = [
  'apple, green, fruit',
  'banana, yellow, fruit',
  'carrot, orange, vegetable'
];

$input = 'green';

$result = null;

foreach ($array as $value) {
  if (str_contains($value, ", $input, ")) {
    $result = strtok($value, ',');   // or: explode(',', value)[0]
    break;
  }
}

print_r($result);   // Output: apple
```

Another possibility is to filter the entries. The result will be an array (think of a case where more than one fruit is having the same color):

```
$input = 'green';

$result = array_filter($array, fn($value) => str_contains($value, ", $input, "));

print_r($result);

// Output:

Array
(
    [0] => apple, green, fruit
)
```